# Get comma separated values and count in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Tables**

**Fruits**

```
f_id  | names
---------------
1   |   Apple
2   |   grapes
3   |   mango
4   |   orange
5   |   cherry
```

Some common table, where I'm storing fruits table f_id is comma separated  or single

**common**

```
id  |   f_id    |   m_id
-------------------------
1   |   1       |   7
2   |   1       |   7
3   |   1       |   7
4   |   3,4     |   8
5   |   2       |   7
6   |   5       |   8
5   |   2       |   9
5   |   2,4     |   9
5   |   4,5     |   9
5   |   1,3     |   10
5   |   2       |   10
```

Now, I want to fetch the data based on m_id. I have m_id 7 if I pass 7 into below query

> SELECT COUNT(C.f_id) as count, C.f_id, (select name from fruits where
>   f_id = C.f_id) as name FROM common C  where C.m_id = 7 group by
>   C.f_id

Based on my query I'm getting the result

```
count   |   f_id    |   name
------------------------------
3       |   1       |   Apple
1       |   2       |   grapes
```

But, I'm failed when I pass 8 OR 9 OR 10 which has comma separated values
and I aslo tried IN() operator and FIND_IN_SET()

> SELECT COUNT(C.f_id) as count, C.f_id, (select name from fruits where
>   f_id IN(C.f_id)) as name FROM common C  where C.m_id = 8 group by
>   C.f_id

How can I fetch the data as I expected for m_id = 8 (I want as per below, please suggest)

```
count   |   f_id    |   name
------------------------------
1       |   3,4     |   Mango, orange
1       |   5       |   cherry
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Yes, But How can I solve this @jarlh

Comment: this is a bad DB Design a corresponding field should have been there that is mapped with csv